# How to use TypeScript definition files from the @types npm repository when --module is 'none'

Tags: typescript, types, module

how can I use TypeScript definition files via @types if the compiler's module system parameter is set to 'none'? For example, when using the type definitions for the express web server:

*npm install @types/express*

with the following tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "module": "none"
    }
}
```

This code fails:

```
import * as express from "express";

export module Web.Server
{
    const app = express();
}
```

with the error message:

> Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module'
>   is 'none'.

If it is not possible to use type definition files in an non-module environment, what is best practice to cope with this situation?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you want to set your module resolution strategy to None when using something like Express (which is when the resolution strategy is almost certainly that of Node).

Comment: How are you planning to include express if you don't import it?

Comment: @Daniel: I see your point. The type definition file uses the commonjs module system. So I'm guessing the two things must fit together. My main project does not use a module system and I wanted just to include an express web server to do some testing.

Comment: @MarkusMauch if your project is targeted to browsers, you probably need to have separate config for scripts using express as they would be targeted to nodejs. And in that config you can you common.js modules.

Comment: This might get easier in the future, but in the mean time, I'd advise you to have a separate `tsconfig.json` for the testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can "import" it with `///` reference directive:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts" />

console.log(_);
```

Answer (score 0):

[typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)

#### main.d.ts

```
export as namespace _dependencies;//from MAIN to MAIN didn't work, need reference

import * as _fs from 'fs'
import * as _path from 'path'
import * as _socket from 'socket.io'
import * as _http from 'http'
import * as _child from 'child_process'

export const fs: typeof _fs
export const path: typeof _path
export const socket: typeof _socket
export const http: typeof _http
export const child: typeof _child
```

#### main.ts

```
/// <reference path="main.d.ts" />
namespace MAIN {
    export const fs: typeof _dependencies.fs = require("fs")
    export const path: typeof _dependencies.path = require("path")
    export const socket: typeof _dependencies.socket = require("socket.io")
    export const http: typeof _dependencies.http = require("http")
    export const child: typeof _dependencies.child = require("child_process")
}

namespace MAIN {
    export module a {
        export function start(_serverPort = 8080) {
            const server = http.createServer(function requestListener() { })
            const io = socket(server);
            server.listen(_serverPort);
            return { io, _serverPort };
        }
    }
}
namespace MAIN {
    export module b { /* ... */ }
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17279#issuecomment-316228569