# TS1148 ~ How to "import" with --module: "none" and typescript 2.x

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, typescript2.0

I'm currently working on a project with some legacy javascript. The application does not include a module loader, it just puts everything as a global into the window object. Touching the legacy code and including a module loader is sadly not a viable option for me.

I want to use typescript for my own code. I set the typescript compiler-option

```
module : "none"
```

in my tsconfig.json and I only used namespaces to organize my own code. Worked well so far.

.. until now:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
..
Rx.Observable.from(['foo',bar']);
...
// Results in TypeScript-Error: 
//   TS1148:Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'.
```

With the "module-none" option set, you can't use import statements in your typescript.
How can you include external libs with this typescript setup?
Is it even possible?

What I tried so far (to include Rx from the RxJs-Library)

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts" />
..
Rx.Observable.from(['foo',bar']);
...
// Results in TypeScript-Error -> TS2304:Cannot find name 'Rx'.
```

In this [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256907/how-to-use-typescript-definition-files-from-the-types-npm-repository-when-mod), Kirill Dmitrenko sugested using an reference-tag, didn´t work for me.

I ended up with this construct.

```
declare const Rx: any;
```

Works, but you loose type-checks and intellisense :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a global declaration for `Rx` which is the type of the RxJS exports, like so:

```
import * as RxJS from "rxjs";

declare global {
    const Rx: typeof RxJS;
}

export {};
```

Save it to a file (e.g. `global.d.ts`) and then add that to the `include` array of `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Im glad my problem could be solved so easily in the end :)

Comment: How do you consume the type then? I tried this with Vue, and my Main.ts couldn't resolve the Vue type.

Comment: @Steve - Once you add this declaration file (must end with `.d.ts`) and add it to `include` in `tsconfig.json` it should be available globally.

Comment: Hmm I was getting compile error saying vue couldn't be found

Comment: @Steve - If you can provide a sample GitHub repo or something of the sort I can take a look; otherwise there's not much I can do with this information.

Comment: @odensc I hosted a repo for you here: https://github.com/makotech222/Vue-AspNetCore-Test

This is basically just a brand new aspnetcore mvc app, i used npm install vue, and tried to use typescript with vue. I can compile, but when i visit in browser, it says it can't find module or whatever.

Comment: @Steve - This is because you do not have a module bundler like webpack and your import statement is not being transpiled. I see you've already made a question about this. If you are concerned about webpack being bloated you could try Parcel.

Comment: @odensc Doesn't browsers like FF and Chrome natively support ES6 modules though? Well, i guess the real issue is that i can't import the type definition for Vue with the Module system, without a module bundler. Thats honestly the only thing i need in my scripts, though, and i don't want to get a bundler just for that :P

Comment: @Steve - They do, but they can't resolve npm modules. That's why you need a bundler.

Comment: @Steve - You can use something like https://unpkg.com/vue in a script tag and then `Vue` will be added to your globals. This would work with the code above. However, I don't see a definition file anywhere in the GitHub repo you linked - all you should need to do is change `RxJS/Rx` to `Vue`.

Comment: Okay i think i'm getting close. I updated the repo. I'm using the global file to define Vue, but it ends up being used in my ts file like

let _vue = new Vue.Vue(). This isn't the correct way in js, its supposed to be just 'new Vue()'

edit: Ooo i got it! changed it in global to be const Vue: typeof Vuejs.Vue

Answer (score 2):

You need to export `rxjs` to the global namespace. There are two ways to do it, depends on the shape of `rxjs`.

If `rxjs` export only one thing, e.g. `Rx.*`, then you can do this:

```
// custom-typings/rxjs.d.ts
import * from 'rxjs'
export as namespace Rx

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "custom-typings"
  ]
}
```

If it export more than one thing, then you need to do global augmentation:

```
// custom-typings/rxjs.d.ts
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'
declare global {
  type Rx = Rx
  ...
}

// same change to tsconfig.json
```

Here are some info on global augmentation.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: I appriciate your effort. Still I had not been able to get this working.

Comment: With RxJs exporting a shitload of stuff - pardon my french - i went for solution #2. But the code snippets you provided, are both giving me errors. 

`Error:(5, 10) TS2456:Type alias 'Rx' circularly references itself.`

So i changed this to: 

`import * as _Rx from 'rxjs';
declare global {
    type Rx = _Rx;
}`

That results  in: 
`Error:(5, 15) TS2304:Cannot find name '_Rx'.`

Pointing to global augmentation seems to be the solution, but I still have trouble to augment it with Rx.

Comment: Check what does the actual typings of `rxjs` export. Maybe you need `import rxjs = require('rxjs')`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Neither did I find another solution, nor can I waste more time searching for one. So I have basically given up on this and reverted back to `declare Rx:any`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a little project (embedded in an existing SharePoint solution) where I am trying to setup the absolute minimal Typescript tooling. I've added the Typescript MSBuild Nuget package, which includes the compiler and allows compile on save (VS2015R3). I had to throw in a `tsconfig.json` because I wanted to enable decorators and add some other tweaks. I don't want a module loader though so I have `module: none`.

Using a lib folder where I manually copied and renamed module.d.ts files, and adding [triple-slash reference directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) in my ts file worked at first, but as soon as I added another file I got warnings about redeclaring globals (because both files have the same references). My solution was to just add another typescript file, move all my triple-slash references there, and replace them in my real Typescript files with one reference to my "base" file. I also threw some other shared code in there and everything works. (I could add the code if that helps, but it is fairly specific to what I'm doing)

It seems like you *could* setup your tsconfig to include this base file in all compiled outputs, but for my use case I just added the base file as another script in my HTML.

I've looked around, and there doesn't seem to be any help regarding this kind of setup. Seems a shame since this is a great way to introduce a team to Typescript without all the tool chain baggage.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually true that you can't import modules. You can do a few things to import modules in this scenario:

1. Target ES6 instead. With `"target": "es6", you can leave` "module": "none"` in place and your imports will work just fine.
2. Change `"module": "none"` to `"module": "commonjs"` and add `"moduleResolution": "node"` - this will provide a means to handle imports in ES5 syntax.